# $.ajax not working with jquery 1.9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My jQuery ajax call works fine with Jquery 1.7. I had to update some code to 1.9 and it doesn't work anymore. This call is part of a contact form. This sends info to a separate database via the curl file. The contact form itself feeds just fine. It's just this code that has stopped working.

If I use this library it functions fine:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

With this library it stops working:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```
function event_listener() {
 $('#submit-btn').click(function() {
    var checkbox = $('#newsletter-signup');
    var emailAddress = $('#email-input').val();


    if (checkbox.attr('checked')) {
      $.ajax({
            url: '/form-curl.php?e=' + emailAddress,
            success: function(r) {
                $("#sales-contact-form").submit();
            }
          });
        } else {
      $("#sales-contact-form").submit();
    }
});



} //end event_listener

$(function(){
  event_listener();
});
```

Comment: *"doesn't seem to work"* is not a proper problem description. What does happen? What errors are showing in console?

Comment: You're right. I totally didn't give enough context. Hopefully my explanation is a bit better now.

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought: the script probably does not reach inside of the `if (checkbox.attr('checked'))`.

According to the **[upgrade guide](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-)** to jQuery 1.9:

> For example, boolean attributes such as `checked` and `disabled` on a
>   checkbox are affected by this change. The correct behavior of
>   `"input[checked]"` is to select checkboxes that have a checked
>   attribute, regardless of its string value, and regardless of their
>   current state.

Sooo, all that `checkbox.attr('checked')` does, is it returns the value of `checked` attribute. End of story.

I assume you need to change this

```
if (checkbox.attr('checked'))
```

to this

```
if (checkbox.is(':checked'))
```

-- which will actually give you a boolean on the **state** of the checkbox.

Comment: or use `prop('checked')` which returns boolean. good catch though on `attr()`

Comment: Yeah, been there, done that. Good info on the `prop` with single param.

Comment: Thanks for your time with my little info on this. prop('checked') is the winner here. Much appreciated.